# how to generate each classes using javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to generate several same class(named "boxed"class) dynamically using javascript functions. This is what I've tried. I want to create same class(named "boxed" class) with given number. The number would be number of column from my csv file. Here is the snapshot of the result and the example code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lag6U.png)

```
<script>
function addClass(var n) {
    var myClass = document.getElementById("boxed")
    for (var i = 0; i< n; i ++){

    }   
}
</script>
```

//

```
<style type="text/css">
 table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

.boxed{
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 10px
}
</style>



<div class="boxed">
  <p>${titile}</p><br>
  <p>${image}</p><br>
  <table class="grid" cellspacing="10">
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>Strongly<br>Disagree</td>
     <td>Disagree</td>
     <td>Neither agree<br/>nor disagree</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Agree&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;Strongly&nbsp;<br>Agree</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="griditem">survey1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="-2">-2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="-1">-1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="0">0</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="1">1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="2">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="griditem">survey2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="-2">-2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="-1">-1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="0">0</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="1">1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="2">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="griditem">survey3</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="-2">-2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="-1">-1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="0">0</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="1">1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="2">2</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using JavaScript if you use jquery this will really simplify your work. It has built in add class function you can simply use this function. You do not have to create it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your function with giving value which is n in function where calling. This is not what you try to seek maybe if you explain more i could fix it for you.Also this loop working btw

```js
function addClass(n) {
    for (var i = 0; i< n; i ++){
  console.log('countet '+i+' times');
    }   
}
window.addClass(100);
```

```css
 table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

.boxed{
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="boxed">
  <p>${titile}</p><br>
  <p>${image}</p><br>
  <table class="grid" cellspacing="10">
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>Strongly<br>Disagree</td>
     <td>Disagree</td>
     <td>Neither agree<br/>nor disagree</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Agree&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;Strongly&nbsp;<br>Agree</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="griditem">survey1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="-2">-2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="-1">-1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="0">0</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="1">1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey1" value="2">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="griditem">survey2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="-2">-2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="-1">-1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="0">0</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="1">1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey2" value="2">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="griditem">survey3</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="-2">-2</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="-1">-1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="0">0</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="1">1</td>
     <td><input type=radio  name="survey3" value="2">2</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to create number of n <div class="boxed"> </div>. Where can I do this work in here?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addClass(var n) { 
    var myClass = [];
    for (var i = 1; i<= n; i ++){
    var val = $('input[name=survey'+i+']:checked').val(); 
       myClass['survey'+i+''].push(val)
    } 
    console.log(myClass);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not clear on what you are trying to do, but I have a feeling you are taking a template and appending the iteration into the class name. If so then your syntax is calling getElementById but your querying the class name.

Perhaps try

```
getElementsByClassName("boxed")
```